# A trivial(?) Topology question

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ is a topological space, and if $B$ is a dense subset of $A$, I am thinking that any subset $C$ containing $B$ is also dense in $A$.

Reason: Let $a\in A$ be given, and $a\not\in C$. The density of $B$ implies the existence of a sequence $b_1,b_2,\ldots$ such that the limit equals $a$. I.e., it is a limit point of $B$. Well since the same sequence lies in $C$, it is a limit point of $C$, hence $C$ is dense in $A$.

Is it true?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be correct.

Comment: It's true in any topological space, that a superset of a dense set is dense. However, your line "the density of $B$ implies the existence of a ***sequence*** $b_1,b_2,\dots$ such that the limit equals $a$" is ***not*** true in general topological spaces. It is true in metric spaces, first-countable spaces, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for sure.  $\overline{B}$ is the **smallest** closed set in $A$ containing $B$, so to say that $B$ is dense in $A$ means that $A$ is the smallest (hence only) closed set containing $B$.  So certainly if $B \subseteq C$ then $\overline{C} = A$ and $C$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. It's a one-liner after you show that for any subsets $A\subset B$ of a topological space, the containment $\overline A\subset\overline B$ holds. Indeed,
$$
\overline A = \bigcap_{\text{closed $E\supset A$}}E,\qquad \overline B = \bigcap_{\text{closed $F\supset B$}}F,
$$
But every closed $F\supset B$ contains $A$, so $\overline A\subset\overline B$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A = \operatorname{cl} B$,  if $B \subseteq C$, then
$$A = \operatorname{cl} B \subseteq \operatorname{cl} C \subseteq A$$
Thus $\operatorname{cl} C = A$, i.e. $C$ is dense.

Comment: Time to learn some Tex/Mathjax? Your answers will be better received if you use it.